# Aave deposit function on polygon says execution reverted

Tags: solidity, remix, polygon, aave

I have here a contract where I can deposit dai into the aave lending pool. I am able to deposit it, but unable to withdraw. Here is the contract:

```
// dai
ERC20 public TOKEN = ERC20(0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063);

ILendingPoolAddressesProvider provider = ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(0xd05e3E715d945B59290df0ae8eF85c1BdB684744);
ILendingPool pool = ILendingPool(provider.getLendingPool());

// put in 1 dai
function putInMoney() external {
    TOKEN.approve(address(pool), 1);
    pool.deposit(address(TOKEN), 1, msg.sender, 0);
}

// dai out 1 dai
function takeOut() external {
    pool.withdraw(address(TOKEN), 1, msg.sender);
}
```

Here is the error that it gives:

```
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
```

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x4a53f02624f8691bdce69c8ec89d9ef27360e3703bdd780e622ef075331d0251

Also, it only deposits 0.000000000000000001 dai instead of 1. I'm not sure why that is.

How can I fix the withdrawal issue and the amount of dai issue?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `putInMoney()` is called, dai is deposited onBehlaf of `msg.sender` (i.e who calls `putInMoney()` function ).

while calling `takeOut()`, you are basically withdrawing the contract's fund to `msg.sender` (i.e who calls `takeOut()` function ), but the contract does not have any funds deposited on its behalf and hence it is failing.

It is depositing 0.000000000000000001 because dai has 18 decimals and the default unit is Wei. so to deposit & withdraw 1 dai, you should change it to:

```
pool.deposit(address(TOKEN), 1 ether, msg.sender, 0);
```

(note: ether is unit, 1 ether = 10**18 wei)
or

```
pool.deposit(address(TOKEN), 10**18, msg.sender, 0);
```

and similarly for withdraw